# Menu que abre ao clicar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo meu site responsivo, e encontrei um menu que se torna um menu hambúrguer dependendo do tamanho da tela, da maneira como eu queria. Porém, o menu abre conforme passe o mouse (e provavelmente o dedo) em cima, e eu gostaria que ele abrisse e fechasse caso clicasse no botão.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
    <nav id="menu">
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';
header {
  background: #F62459;
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #F62459;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#logo {
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(logo.svg) no-repeat center;
  display: block;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#menu-icon {
  background: url(menu-icon.png) no-repeat center;
  display: hidden;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
header {
    position: absolute;
}
#menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #c5c5c5;
    right: 10px;
    top: 65px;
    width: 35%;
}
nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $('#menu-icon').on('click', function() {
        $('#menu').slideToggle('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seu menu já enta funcionando no `.on('click')` repare no script dele... Repare tb que para ele funcionar precisa de jQuery indexado no documento.

Comment: Você removeu a pergunta `Exibir se dado já existe no banco dentro do formulário`. Acabei de desenvolver uma resposta para ela, veja funcionando em http://kithomepage.com/sos/lua.html

Comment: Leo, eu restaurei a postagem, será que você poderia responder lá?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu menu já está funcionando no click repare que ele é `.on('click')`

No entanto seu menu tem uns problemas de CSS que vc ainda precisa corrigir, pois ele está quebrando a linha antes de entrar o css que recolhe o menu. Além disso `display:hidden` não existe, acredito que deveria ser `display:none`...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo fiz alguns ajustes de css e no script... pois o toggle estava escondendo o menu inteiro inclusive o próprio btn o correto seri `'#menu ul'`

Veja como fica no código:

```js
$('#menu-icon').on('click', function () {
    $('#menu ul' ).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';

header {
    background: #F62459;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #F62459;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px
}

a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logo {
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(https://unsplash.it/100/50) no-repeat center;
        display: block;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#menu-icon {
    background: url(https://unsplash.it/32/32) no-repeat center;
        display: none;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    header {
        position: absolute;
    }

    #menu-icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #c5c5c5;
        right: 10px;
        top: 65px;
        width: 35%;
    }

   /* nao precisa desse css
nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
} */

    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<header>
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
    <nav id="menu">
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Obrigada Hugo, como não tenho tanta prática com o java acabo me confundindo. Tá tudo funcionando como eu queria!

Comment: @lua Legal que bom que resolveu ai, na verdade seu js estava praticamente certo só que vcs estava referenciando o elemento errado. No mais boa sorte ai